# Show and hide form

Tags: javascript

I have a row which has a form.

```
<div class="row display_magic" id="magic">
<h1>helloworld</h1>
</div>
```

and this is my style.

```
.display_magic {
    display: none;
}
```

And this is my javascript that I wrote,

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

And this is the button that triggers the function

```
<button onclick="showDiv()"> Add new request</button>
```

So right now its hidden and when I click the button it appears, all I need to do now is make it disappear when the button is clicked again. 
It is a must that its hidden in the start.

Comment: Check whether `style.display` is `block` and if it is make it `none`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```js
function showDiv() {
   if(document.getElementById('magic').style.display == "block")
       document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "none";
  else
      document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
.display_magic {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row display_magic" id="magic">
<h1>helloworld</h1>
</div>

<button onclick="showDiv()"> Add new request</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="toggleDiv()"> Add new request</button>  

<script>
      var visible = false;

    function toggleDiv() {
      visible ? document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "none" : document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block";

      visible = !visible;
    } </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a condition to your function to first check if it is displayed or not, and act accordingly. You can use ternary operator to make it in one line:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('magic').style.display = document.getElementById('magic').style.display == "none"?"block":"none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your showDiv() function to:

```
function showDiv() {
if(document.getElementById('magic').style.display === "block"){
document.getElementById(text).style.display = 'none';}
else{document.getElementById(text).style.display = 'block';}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<script>
    var hasShow=false;
    function showDiv(){
         if(hasShow){
              document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "none";
              hasShow=false;
         }else{
              document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block";
              hasShow=true;
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite the method like this

```
function showDiv() {
if(document.getElementById('magic').style.display=='none'){
document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block";
}else{
document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "none";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle examle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a1tp80b/)

```
var showDiv = function () {
   var magic = document.getElementById('magic');
   magic.style.display === "block" ? magic.style.display = "none" : magic.style.display = "block"
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', showDiv, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would benefit from a "toggle" function

How it is right now:

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('magic').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

How it would be then:

```
<script>
function toggleVisibility(elementId) {
    var visible = "block";
    var hidden = "none";

    var visibility = document.getElementById(elementId).style.display;
    if(visibility == visible) 
        display = hidden;
    else
        visibility = visible;

    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = visibility;
}

function showDiv() { // maybe "toggleDiv" would be a better name for this now
   toggleVisibility("magic");
}
</script>
```

Bonus: you have a function to toggle visibilities you can reuse

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jquery toggle for this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#magic").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button> Add new request</button>

<div class="row display_magic" id="magic">
<h1>helloworld</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```